# Field collection structure using entity wrapper

Tags: entities

I have a requirement on a site where users have:

1. Membership periods and
2. parents or guardians.

Both can have an unlimited number of instances, and are similar in setup.
The first is a Field Collection (FC) with a string list and a date.
The second is a field collection with a string list and two other text fields.

I am making status fields for both fields using a computed field and entity wrapper.

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
foreach($wrapper->field_membership_type_periodical as $period) {
...
```

This one is working as expected and it loops over every "`field_membership_type_periodical`" FC added to the user, and I can use all other properties of this FC as expected.

When I do the same for the "`field_parents_guardian`" FC, although I have added items to the list, it doesn't iterate over it and if I dump the `field_parents_guardian->value()`, it says it is an empty array.

If I dump the whole wrapper object, I find it strange that the "`field_membership_type_periodical`" is dumped as:

```
[field_membership_type_periodical] => Array
                (
                    [und] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => 1
                                    [revision_id] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )
```

While the guardian field is dumped as:

```
[field_parents_guardian] => Array
                (
                    [und] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [field_parents_guardian_type] => Array
                                        (
                                            [und] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [value] => Vader
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [entity] => FieldCollectionItemEntity Object
                                        (
                                            [fieldInfo:protected] => 
                                            [hostEntity:protected] => 
                                            [hostEntityId:protected] => 
...
```

So the first one it seems, is merely a reference to the FC item, which it will probably load when the property is asked for, while the second one seems to be having no reference information, but the object itself already loaded.

Both FCs have been setup in the same way and I can't find any major differences in their settings.
What might cause this strange behaviour in structure and could it be the source of the "empty list issue"?